# Conditionally displaying a follow button for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to achieve is a follow button that is toggled when the user clicks it. This goes in the users_helper.rb helper. Here's what I have.

The line I need help with is "elsif current_user != @user"

What I'm trying to do here is to remove the follow button for the user's own profile, since he cannot follow himself.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
def render_follow_conditionally
    if user_signed_in?
    follow_toggler 
    else
    button_to "Follow", new_user_session_path, class: 'btn btn-lake'
    end
end

def follow_toggler
    if current_user.following? @user
      button_to "Followed", unfollow_user_path(@user), class: 'btn btn-default'
    elsif current_user != @user
      button_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user), class: 'btn btn-default'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare users by their ids

```
elsif current_user.id != @user.id
```